# How do I define Type with strings versus object literal properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've poured over the TS docs, but can't seem to find an answer as to why the following is illegal.

I'm able to define a union type with strings, yet if I create the same union type with references to object properties, which ultimately references the same string values, the compiler isn't happy.

[Demo via typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUFcGNoUwM4ILACg4A8AOB7ATgC6gECeWcE+BA8ngCZx4DqAlgQBbgF4sB2A5glABeUAHIAhgmhjQAH3ENpYgNxo0mXIVDQcvBEXBVaDPFwkEW0EaADeaUKACC4AMIAucVJkAaB6AARAFE3TzElXzQAX3VUEFAAMQkWABsNbCpiMgojQhNGVg5qACMAKzhoIlFcmnpGc0toADoXV3lKPLqzAgsrJuC3FSA)

```js
// Success
export type SortOrderWithStrings = 'asc' | 'desc';

export const SortOrderStatic = {
  ASC: 'asc',
  DESC: 'desc',
}

// Fail
export type SortOrderWithObject = SortOrderStatic.ASC | SortOrderStatic.DESC;
```

The errors are as follows. Why is this a namespace issue?

```
Cannot find namespace 'SortOrderStatic'
Exported type alias 'SortOrderReference' has or is using private name 'SortOrderType'
```

Ultimately, it'd be nice to have a `Column` interface the defines the supported sort order types, while then instancing a `Column` with `SortOrderStatic` to avoid magic strings, but per the above, this doesn't seem possible.

```js
interface Column {
  label: string;
  defaultSortOrder: SortOrderWithObject;
}

const MyColumn: Column = {
  label: 'My Column',
  defaultSortOrder: SortOrderStatic.ASC
}
```

If I define the interface as follows (with `SortOrderWithStrings`), and then attempt to use `SortOrderStatic`, the compiler once again isn't happy.

```
interface Column {
  label: string;
  defaultSortOrder: SortOrderWithStrings;
}

const MyColumn: Column = {
  label: 'My Column',
  defaultSortOrder: SortOrderStatic.ASC
}
```

Fails with:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SortOrderWithStrings'.
```

It's clear I'm missing something fundamental here, and I appreciate any insight.

Comment: "It's clear I'm missing something fundamental here" yes, you are confusing *compile-time* with *runtime*. Unless the *compile-time type* is a literal string, the compiler cannot guarantee that the runtime access of an object property is the string you think it is. Your object property is type `string`, which means at runtime it could be *any* string. The string literal is immutable (and so statically verifiable), the object property access not so much.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks, okay, that makes sense. I'm wondering if the compiler could infer the expected runtime type if `SortOrderStatic` was of type `interface { [x: string]: string; }`. Would that not be explicit enough?

Comment: In this case I would use [an enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks, your updated comment did it for me I think. There's no way the compiler can know what my eventual `ASC` is going to be.

Comment: Exactly. Almost every problem people (including me when I started!) have with TS comes from that conflation.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks, I appreciate the quickness. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it once the time limit passes.

Comment: Answer added, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's clear I'm missing something fundamental here

Yes, you are confusing compile-time with runtime: unless the *compile-time type* is a literal string, the compiler cannot guarantee that the runtime access of an object property is the string you think it is. Your object property is type `string`, which means at runtime it could be *any* string.

The string literal is immutable (and so statically verifiable), the object property access not so much.

In your particular case I would just use [an enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html):

```
enum SortOrder {
  ASC = 'ASC',
  DESC = 'DESC',
}

export { SortOrder }

import { SortOrder } from 'something';
SortOrder.ASC; // ASC as a string
```

This will maintain type-safety, you can't pass any ol' string to something that expects a `SortOrder`: ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAyg9gJwC4HkEBNgKgbwFBRQCCMAwlALxQDkJp1ANAVACICiZlN7ZjeAvnjwAzMCADGSAJZwQUYXDgAKAB4AuWIlQYsASlzNxsgM5wANsAB0ZuAHNVugNwChC5fGRpMCS3ScjFJWoAQxAATyhjJAQpEFtqfyA))